# Newbie Questions About Linux Server

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu

Hi i am new to linux and just trying to get to learn it a bit more i am in no way a computer amatuer just when it comes to linux

anyways i want to setup a home file server it basically will just be for storage of files and streaming them over the network and the occasional usenet download

I am looking at several options and because i am new i want to go with a GUI until i am more comfortable what i was looking at was using Lubuntu however it does not have a LTS version so i was thinking of using the LTS of Ubuntu Server and then installing the lubuntu desktop over the top however i have a few questions

Once i install this gui will it still access the LTS sources so it is supported for the full LTS period (2016-2017 if i remember correctly)

is there any real difference between the desktop and server editions of ubuntu apart from GUI vs CLI and different software (will i notice any performance or network throughput by choosing the server edition over the desktop edition)

i am just trying to see what advantages the ubuntu server edition has over the desktop

Comment: You should really try to have one question per… uh… question, so that you can accept a single answer. I don't quite understand, but I think your main question is: "What are the differences between desktop and server editions of Ubuntu?" If that is correct, then you can clarify by editing the title. I'm not sure if there are other clear questions that you have in these paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you just want to setup a light weight secure file server, you can use the desktop version of Ubuntu and to setup a sftp server on it.

See the site below for detailed steps.

http://blog.markvdb.be/2009/01/sftp-on-ubuntu-and-debian-in-9-easy.html

Other remote machines can access your server by Filezilla or other tools which understand sftp or ssh.

Comment: This doesn't really state why user155045 should install the desktop edition over the server edition.